# How to write real cron job in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have done `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');` in `wp-config.php`.

I set up the cron path but I actually do not know how to write code so that calling that URL will execute my code. I want to write real cron job over WordPress cron job.

I tried with this in `function.php` but it did not work:

```
if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_hourly_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
}
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? What do you mean by "how to write code so that calling that URL will execute my code"? That's exactly what PHP does when configured normally on a web server. Cron is designed to do something very different: It runs code _on a schedule_, without any action from users.

Comment: Note that WordPress cron job action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the post that solve it for me:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job

Takeaways:

- You seem to have prepared everything correctly - your code schedules the execution of `do_this_hourly` function every hour. However, due to `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');` in `wp-config.php` the function is only scheduled and never executed unless you make a request to `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` yourself.
- The only thing left to do is to setup system cron
- If you are on Unix-based system (Linux/Mac), then try `crontab -e` from the command line on your server, and add a line like this:
  `wget -q -O - http://yourwebsite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1`

Don't forget to replace `http://yourwebsite.com` with whatever your website domain is.

Good luck!